# Is it possible to refresh/use someone else Google Calendar?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-calendar-api

We're developing an app using google's calendar api. The problem we've encountered and can't solve is : 
Let's call the first user : "A", and the second one : "B". 
When A and B subscribe to our app, they can interact with each other's calendar (indirectly). It means if A creates and event, it is gonna update the B's calendar. This does only work on short term use (because they created a new token and refresh token works if they stay a bit longer). If B comes back 2 days later and creates an event, it is not gonna reach A's calendar because A's token is down.

In other words, is there any way to update someone's token even when he is not logged in so everyone can still access other one's calendar?

[the picture shows the error I get when i reach the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F82sk.png)

Thank you everybody!

Comment: When you say "update the B's calendar", do you mean create an event on B? Or invite B to an event created in A?

Comment: I need to refresh B’s calendar to update the info we have on him before creating the new event. So it matches the new calendar and not an old version of it